# Is there a way to define a table of object references?

Tags: generics, cobol

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to define a table where each item on it has a usage of object reference.

According to the latest COBOL standard the usage object reference can only be defined in a 01-level data item, and tables cannot be defined on 01-level data items. So this would seem like a table of objects is not allowed, right?

I'm trying to write something like a `List<T>` using tables and generics, but this issue would make it impossible to make a generic list of objects. I need a sanity check, am I missing something? Is it possible to define a table of objects in COBOL?

If not, is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You can define a table of specific objects.  You define the object in WORKING-STORAGE at the 01 level.  You can then define a table where each object is PIC X(N), where N is not less than the length of the object in bytes.

Comment: Hey @GilbertLeBlanc, this would not work because there's no guarantee that the value in those objects are Alphanumeric, specially when combined with generics.

Comment: Everything in the COBOL world is alphanumeric.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's not true, specially with pointers and object references. You can't assign a raw pointer or object reference into an alphanumeric item and expect to get a valid alphanumeric value back (not even sure if that would compile). This applies to COBOL object references as well, because they are pointing to an object and not to a group item or elementary item.

Answer (score 0):

With Micro Focus COBOL you can do:

```
   class-id. MyItem public.
   01 MyField binary-long public.
   end class.

   program-id. example.
   01  mylist list[type MyItem].
```

I should also add this code compiles to JVM bytecode and IL (.NET Framework and .NET 6)

What do you think KTSnowy?